# FlagName to JSON

Tags: json, haskell

I need to convert values of type `Distribution.PackageDescription.FlagName` to a JSON object with the `Text.JSON` of the `json` package.
I ended up with the following approach:

```
instance JSON FlagName where
    showJSON (FlagName n) = makeObj [ ("FlagName", showJSON n) ]
    readJSON object = do
        obj <- readJSON object
        flag <- valFromObj "FlagName" obj
        return flag
```

When I try to encode a value and decode it again the following happens:

```
> showJSON (FlagName "foo")  
JSObject (JSONObject {fromJSObject = [("FlagName",JSString (JSONString {fromJSString = "foo"}))]})  
> readJSON (showJSON (FlagName "foo")) :: Result FlagName  
Error "Unable to read JSObject"
```

I guess the error is in that line: `obj <- readJSON object`
How do I force Haskell to use the `readJSON` function from the `JSON String` instance ?

**Update:** I found now a rather hackish solution:

```
instance JSON FlagName where
    showJSON (FlagName n) = makeObj [ ("FlagName", showJSON n) ]

    readJSON object = do
        obj <- readJSON (showJSON (FlagName "foo")) :: Result (JSObject JSValue)
        let maybeFlagName = lookup "FlagName" $ fromJSObject obj
        maybe (fail "Not a FlagName object") (\jsn -> liftM FlagName $ (readJSON jsn :: Result String)) maybeFlagName
```

I'd appreciate it if someone comes up with a more elegant solution ...

Comment: Note that code is best formatted by indenting 4 spaces rather than using the HTML `<pre>` or `<code>` (you can select the block of code and use the button labelled `{}` to indent efficiently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself:
`valFromObj` returns the name of the `FlagName` (i.e. a `String`) rather than the `FlagName` itself.

```
instance JSON FlagName where
    showJSON (FlagName n) = makeObj [ ("FlagName", showJSON n) ]
    readJSON object = do
        obj <- readJSON object
        n <- valFromObj "FlagName" obj
        return $ FlagName n
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to pattern match so you can handle the case when object is no of `JSObject`. Instead of fail you can do some other thing. You will need to `import Control.Applicative` to use `<$>`. I just like the applicative syntax better for such things.

```
 instance JSON FlagName where
     showJSON (FlagName n) = makeObj [ ("FlagName", showJSON n) ]
     readJSON (JSObject obj) = FlagName <$> valFromObj "FlagName" obj
     readJSON _ = fail "unknown object"
```

Comment: Yeah, indeed, you could squash the last two lines of my solution to your `FlagName <$> valFromObj "FlagName" obj`. I like it. But I'm not sure if the pattern matching is a convenient way to extract the `JSValue` from the `JSObject`. I'd rather prefer the use of `readJSON`.